# Using mouse to paint row of characters in ncurses

Tags: c, mouseevent, mouse, drag, ncurses

I'm trying to use ncurses to paint a row of characters on the screen with the mouse. I'm able to distinguish between a BUTTON1_CLICKED event and BUTTON1_RELEASED event on the screen, but haven't figured out how to paint between them.

The following code prints BUTTON1_CLICKED and BUTTON1_RELEASED at their event positions:

```
void obstacle_draw(WINDOW * boardWin, int array[LINES][COLS]) {

int ch;
MEVENT event;

keypad(boardWin, TRUE);
mousemask(BUTTON1_CLICKED | BUTTON1_RELEASED | REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION, NULL);
mouseinterval(0);  

while(1) {
    ch = wgetch(boardWin);   
    if (ch == KEY_MOUSE) {   
        getmouse(&event);
        if (event.bstate & BUTTON1_CLICKED) {
            wattron(boardWin, COLOR_PAIR(BLACK_ON_WHITE) | A_REVERSE);
            mvwprintw(boardWin, event.y, event.x, "CLICKED at %d,%d", event.y, event.x);
            wrefresh(boardWin);
        } else if (event.bstate & BUTTON1_RELEASED) {
                wattron(boardWin, COLOR_PAIR(BLACK_ON_WHITE) | A_REVERSE);
            mvwprintw(boardWin, event.y, event.x, "RELEASED at %d,%d", event.y, event.x);
            wrefresh(boardWin);
        }  
    }
    if (ch == '\n') {
        break;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Adding the following line before my while loop allows me to paint these coordinates once I've made the first mouse click, and without holding the button. But I can't seem to turn it off (I also don't understand how it works):

```
printf("\033[?1003h\n");
```

I feel like I've read every ncurses mouse post on stack overflow. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [mousemask](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_mouse.3x.html#h3-mousemask) function is used for this:

> To make mouse events visible, use the **`mousemask`**  function.   This  will
>          set  the  mouse events to be reported.  By default, no mouse events are
>          reported.  The function will return a mask to  indicate  which  of  the
>          specified  mouse events can be reported; on complete failure it returns
>          0.  If *oldmask* is non-NULL, this function fills the indicated  location
>          with the previous value of the given window's mouse event mask.
>
> As  a  side  effect,  setting  a  zero *mousemask* may turn off the mouse
>          pointer; setting a nonzero mask may turn it on.  Whether  this  happens
>          is device-dependent.

That's actually two questions.  The one specific to ncurses is how to turn the mouse off/on (using `printf` is guaranteed to provide disappointment).  The other question is how to enable "any event", and is terminal-specific, seen by ncurses as a different initialization string for the mouse.  The terminal descriptions [xterm-1002](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1002) and [xterm-1003](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1003) provide examples of this.  The **`XM`** capability (which is what ncurses looks at) is described in the [user_caps](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/user_caps.5.html) manual page.

Just in case there's a **third** question, the pros/cons of turning the any-event mode have been mentioned a few times on the [*bug-ncurses*](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=xterm-1002&submit=Search%21&idxname=bug-ncurses&max=20&result=normal&sort=score) mailing list.

Comment: Thank you. I've included the mousemask function, but it's not clear to me how to check for a sustained depress of button1. A click and a release are both events, whereas I think I need to test for a state (depressed / not depressed). There doesn't seem to be much documentation out there on this particular question.